# Querying multiple tables using jpa repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Suppose if I have 3 entities - `User`, `Skills`, `Department` 
and I have repositories corresponding to all of them - `UserRepository`, `SkillRepository`, `DepartmentRepository`.

I understand that the relation mapping between entities i.e. one-one many-many should be specified in the respective entity classes.  The question is I want to use all of the 3 entities in a query. How would I do it? A single repository is associated with only one entity right? So, how/where would I write it?

Comment: What are you trying to do when you say _I want to use all of the 3 entities in a query_? Post your problem with relevant bits of code and seek for help. You question is _vague_ and please lookup Spring data jpa documentation for what you want

Answer (score 1):

As there are many different ways to specify queries with Spring Data JPA there are various answers to this.

1. Maybe you don't have to. If entity `A` references `B` and you just want to get the `B`s with your `A` you simply use your `ARepository` to load `A`s and use object navigation to get your `B`s. You might read up on eager and lazy loading for more information about how to control this.
2. If you want referenced entities in the where condition you can use property paths in your query method names: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions
3. If you are using `@Query` annotations you can do (almost) whatever you want with JPQL. Among others, you may as well navigate properties to use them in where clauses.

In general, you'd put that query in the matching repository based on the primary entity returned.